# What is difference between in inject vs viewmodel in Android koin

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I'm using Koin 3.2 which has the new module includes feature. I am want to know what is the difference between the use of `by inject()` or `by viewmodel()`.

```
val viewModel by inject<MainActivityViewModel>()
```

or

```
val viewModel by viewmodel<MainActivityViewModel>()
```

in viewmodel. I know both works correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is `by viewmodel` will hook to register the instance to your Lifecycle. Where a simple `by inject` just create the instance